# Why is the search box not sticking to the right?

Tags: html, css

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;

}

.nav{
    background-color:bisque;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;

}

.b{
    height: 60px;
    width: 10%;
    background-color: antiquewhite;
    margin: 2px;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Anton', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 20px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
img{
    width: 80px;
    height: 60px;
}

#srch{
width: 10%;
height:60px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lost and Found</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Anton&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="nav" >
        <img src="img.png" alt="logo" srcset="">
        <div class="b"><span>Electronincs</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Plastics</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Wearables</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Others</span></div>
        <input id="srch" type="search" value="Search">
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

The first code is Style.css while the 2nd code for Html file. Why is the search box not sticking to the right ? What mistake have i made ? I am not able to understand.The code is self explantory.
The searchbox has the id #srch. I am designing the nav bar and am a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going with this **float** approach you could do something like,

```
<div class="nav" >
    <div class="nav-items">
        <img src="img.png" alt="logo" srcset="">
        <div class="b"><span>Electronincs</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Plastics</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Wearables</span></div>
        <div class="b"><span>Others</span></div>
    </div>
    <input id="srch" type="search" value="Search">
</div>


.nav{
    background-color:bisque;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    display: flex; 
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

justify-content: space-between takes care of positioning the search box to the right and other items to the left.

Also note that, I added an extra div class "nav-items". It helps to separate other items with search box

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid `float: right;` and use instead of it a `margin-left: auto;` on the input.

You can put it into div for the better layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `right: 0;` to move your search bar to the right.

```css
#srch {
    width: 10%;
    height:60px;
    
    /* these 2 lines should do the trick! */
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```